# CakePHP onClick for form->end

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I would like to include a javascript function for preventing user from submiting form twice, but I just cannot call the function on submit click. Here is what I have tried:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Save'), array('onclick'=>'submit();'));?>
```

I went through the documentation and it seems that the Form->end does not take such parameters, which is really odd. Can that be true?

Any information or help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you need to do in this way : -

```
$options = array(
    'label' => 'submit',
    'div' => FALSE,
    'onclick'=>'submit()'
);
echo $this->Form->end($options);
```

This will generate :-

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit()">
```

Documentation : [Click Here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#closing-the-form)

Comment: This seems to work, but in this case the cakePHP front end field validation is not working. Any way to get the onclick working with the validation?

Comment: if you are submitting the form with javascript/jquery then you need to validate form with javascript/jquery.

Comment: What I use the is html attribute `required`. But with the previously mentioned onclick this is not required.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use onSubmit in `$this->Form->create()`

```
$this->Form->create('Model', array(
    'onsubmit' => 'return submit();',
     //other create options
)
```

And in your JavaScript use a flag to keep track if the form was submitted, and return false if it has. If it hasn't return true and the form will submit.

You might also want to disable the submit button the first time the form is submitted to make it clear to the user that the form can't be submitted again.